# Issues Installing And Running Pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm sorry to ask about a question I've seen here before, but none of the answers I've gone through seem to fix the issue. I've followed installation documentation for running pyspark on my local machine. Once done, I'm trying to test the installation using

```
# Start pyspark via provided command
import pyspark

# Below code is Spark 2+
spark = pyspark.sql.SparkSession.builder.appName('test').getOrCreate()

spark.range(10).collect()
```

But I keep getting the following error:

```
/Users/usr123/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/bin/spark-class: line 71: /usr/bin/java/bin/java: Not a directory
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 5, in <module>
    spark = pyspark.sql.SparkSession.builder.appName('test').getOrCreate()
  File "/Users/usr123/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/sql/session.py", line 173, in getOrCreate
    sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(sparkConf)
  File "/Users/usr123/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/context.py", line 349, in getOrCreate
    SparkContext(conf=conf or SparkConf())
  File "/Users/usr123/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/context.py", line 115, in __init__
    SparkContext._ensure_initialized(self, gateway=gateway, conf=conf)
  File "/Users/usr123/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/context.py", line 298, in _ensure_initialized
    SparkContext._gateway = gateway or launch_gateway(conf)
  File "/Users/usr123/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/java_gateway.py", line 94, in launch_gateway
    raise Exception("Java gateway process exited before sending its port number")
Exception: Java gateway process exited before sending its port number
```

Has anyone found a good way to ensure the correction of this issue? Is there something obvious I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar issues, for us dropping the version of python to 3.6 was solving the issues, it seemed to be a case of incompatible conda environment in our case.
Which exact version of spark are you trying to run? It can be a substantial difference between 2.1, 2.3, 2.4.

Comment: When I try to get my spark version, I get `/Users/usr123/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/bin/spark-class: line 71: /usr/bin/java/bin/java: Not a directory` error. Does this mean something needs to be done about the jdk used?

Comment: That usally means java installation is expected to be there. If you have jave installed somewhere else you need to repoint your settings to java installation. The fact that it says it is not a directory probably just means that path doesnt exists. Which java do you have installed? Did you set up JAVA_HOME variable?

Comment: I have not set up JAVA_HOME. I downloaded and installed jdk-8u251-macosx-x64.dmg

Comment: if you run "java -version" it returns you expected value?
did you add JAVA_HOME to your bash_profile ?
also some components require java_home varible to be set as well